# Defaultvalue on date select jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [Jquery Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) . Is it possible to do so, that when I select a date, then time is automatically set to `23.59`, but if I change the time manually then it keeps the time value?

I dont want the datetime showing until i select a date or time. But currently all the solutions that I have found are about setting a default value that you can see when the element is loaded.

```
<input size="15" class="timePicker" name="name" id="id" style="width: 100%" />

jQuery('.timePicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

SOLUTION

Apparently it turns out, that in the timepicker sourcecode options hour and minute are ignored and not used. Solution for that would be to open up the timepicker.js, find the _newInst function and then either change the corresponding lines, or you could just override the prototype method with a method that has the required fixes.

Comment: POST YOU CODE HERE !

Answer (score 0):

So simple just change the default timepicker values before calling the time picker as below :

```
$.timepicker._defaults.hour = 23;
$.timepicker._defaults.minute = 59;

var jq = jQuery('.timePicker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

see this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/jy8Lufd7/1/) .

Comment: are you sur , try to reset cache , because fiddle working properly !

Comment: reset cashe, recompiled everything, check with debug. Nope. not working

Comment: where do you pust the `$.timepicker._defaults.hour = 23;` ... in your code , is it in a ready block or before , otherwise could you post you code structure here ?

Comment: just show your code to see where the problem is stuated , ps does the fiddle work properly for you ??

Comment: yes fiddle works. i did exactly what you did. And it just does not work. Might be the issue of project scale. Its a very large project and maybe somewhere there is a call to a function that overrides everything.

Comment: could you check in yuor browser console the $.timepicker._defaults.hour value ?

Comment: @bRIMOs The value is 0. If ii set it to 23 then it is 23. But it does not seem to affect the datetime picker. According to the documentation jQuery('#id').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        hour: '23',
        minute: '59'
    }); should work. But it doesent.

Comment: I think that something went wrong in your code structure .